# concatenation of two unicode srings?

Tags: python, unicode, concatenation

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
separators = [u"।", u",", u"."]
dat=open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\text4.txt",'r').read()
text=dat.decode("utf-8")
wros=text.split()
out=""
import string
space=" "
counter=0;
for word in wros:
        out=u" ".join(word)

writ=open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\text5.txt",'w')
writ.write(out.encode('utf-8'))
writ.close()
```

text4.txt contains `भारत का इतिहास काफी समृद्ध एवं विस्तृत है।`

text5.txt outputs as `ह ै ।`

desired output is `भारत का इतिहास काफी समृद्ध एवं विस्तृत है।`

please tell me what i am doing is wrong ? HElp required ! thanks in advance

Comment: every time you assign `out = u" ".join(word)` you're losing the previous value assigned to `out`. You might want to use a list and `append` instead (but it's not clear what exactly you're trying to do since the `join` statement in your case adds a space between each character of each word which is not your desired output).

Comment: Your problem is in the for loop... you keep discarding the string in `out` each time it loops. The loop also adds spaces between each character of the words. It looks like you want output that is the same as input... can you tell us what the conversion should do.

Comment: you don't need `for` - you need only `out = u" ".join(wros)`

Comment: @tdelaney i need the for loop to edit few words . so as to get different result .

Comment: if you need `for` loop then show it in code. Now you don't need this `for`

Comment: @furas i need the for loop in order to iter between different words of wros

Comment: @furas what part of code? for loop is in the code.

Comment: I would create list `out = []` and in for-loop I would append words to the list `out.append(word)` and afters for-loop I would concatenate list into one string `result = u" ".join(out)`

Comment: In `for-loop` you have only `out=u" ".join(word)` which you can do without `for-loop`. So show what else you do in `for-loop` - why do you need this for-loop`.

Comment: @sirfz if i used a list and then used     list.append(word) i cannot encode it again. can i?

Comment: In your example, the input and output strings are identical. From the example, you shouldn't have done anything at all. I could post an answer adding spaces between all letters in the words (that appears to be what you code is trying to do), but that wouldn't match your desired output.

Comment: You could join the list and encode that `u" ".join(wros).encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: As an aside, considering moving to python 3.x if you can. Its unicode support works better.

Comment: @furas let it be anything what i do in for loop... but at the end i need to concat after operating on each word i need to add space between previous sets of word and then new word.

Comment: @tdelaney i am encoding it after when i am writing back to the file as

Comment: writ.write(out.encode('utf-8'))

Comment: @tdelaney there is word i  am looping with not in wros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you have to do with `word` but I would do it this way:

```
text = open('text4.txt').read()

text = text.decode("utf-8")

# split one string into list of (old) words
words = text.split()

# list for new words
out = []

# modify words
for word in words:
    # here - do something with `word`
    out.append(word)

# concatenate all new words to one string 
result = u' '.join(out)

result = result.encode('utf-8')

writ = open('text5.txt', 'w')
writ.write(result)
writ.close()
```

Comment: thanks man so much thanks .. i was confused where to put that result = u' '.join(out)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a template:

```
# no need for coding:utf8 unless *source code* has non-ASCII.

import io # Contains modern version of open compatible with Python 3.

# Use with and file is automatically closed when block is exited.
with io.open(r'c:\users\user\desktop\text4.txt',encoding='utf8') as dat:
    text = dat.read()

words = text.split()

#edit words

text = u' '.join(words)

with io.open(r'c:\users\user\desktop\text5.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as writ:
    writ.write(text)
```